# scaffold asp.net menu in web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, webforms

I’m creating a shopping website by using asp.net and c#. So I need my menu to be linked to the table directly (aka bind). Since I’m building this site from ground up, the database design can be changed for this purpose. My category table is the one that I’m trying to bind it to menu control and it contains the following columns:

```
    cat_id bigint, cat_name nvarchar(200), cat_parent bigint
```

So for each item I have a parent. I have no clue on how can I do this kind of binding?

Comment: I'm a lil' bit off topic but why don't you try developing it in MVC 3 ?

Comment: can't. it has to be web form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this instance, i'd probably setup a CTE stored procedure (to get a hierarchical structure), and return the table from sql to the Repeater control (or whatever control you are using).

that way your parent-child data is already returned in the correct order.

Comment: they won't return completely in correct order but almost. the levels of hierarchy are not shown in the result set. that way will end up in dirty code which is full of LINQ or foreach statements to fill the menu in correct hierarchy format.